# Creating a dynamic StringSelectMenu in DiscordJS v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to create a dynamic StringSelectMenu generated when a specific command is used. Is there a way to do this? Because I am getting the problem at the .addOptions() of the StringSelectMenuBuilder().

Relevant Code (Looping through the Database entries (at the moment just 1))
The relevant object is stringselect, which should create the input for the .addOptions()

```
                console.log(result);
                if (result) {
                    let string = "";
                    let stringselect = "";

                    for (entry in result) {
                        id = result[entry].id;
                        name = result[entry].name;
                        money1 = result[entry].money1;
                        money2 = result[entry].money2;
                        amount = result[entry].amount;

                        string += `${name} (Item id = ${id}). The price is ${money1} Coin(s), ${money2} Diamond(s). There are ${amount} availible of this item.

`;
                        stringselect += `{label: "${name}",description: "Of the item ${name1} with the id ${id} are ${amount} availible. The price is ${money1} Coin(s), ${money2} Diamond(s).",value: ${id}},`;
                    }
```

This is the code of the SelectMenu creation

```
                    const select = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
                        new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                            .setCustomId("reward-buy")
                            .setPlaceholder("Nothing selected")
                            .addOptions(stringselect)
                    );
```

I have tried different techniques, with JSON, other formats and everything but I am stuck at the error that it is missing the requried properties. I do not know and did not find an answer how to create the options input dynamically. I would not need the specific code to finish it, just how I should pass the values.

The error is:

```
CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
    at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1212:70)
    at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1068:47)
    at ObjectValidator.handle (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1165:17)
    at ObjectValidator.parse (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
    at /home/test/test/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:654:134
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at StringSelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (/home/test/test/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:653:18)
    at StringSelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (/home/test/test/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/StringSelectMenuBuilder.js:48:18)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/test/test/src/commands/reward-shop.js:67:9)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/test/test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) {
  errors: [
    [
      'label',
      MissingPropertyError: A required property is missing
          at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1187:27)
          at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1068:47)
          at ObjectValidator.handle (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1165:17)
          at ObjectValidator.parse (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
          at /home/test/test/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:654:134
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
          at StringSelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (/home/test/test/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:653:18)
          at StringSelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (/home/test/test/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/StringSelectMenuBuilder.js:48:18)
          at Query.<anonymous> (/home/test/test/src/commands/reward-shop.js:67:9)
          at Query.<anonymous> (/home/test/test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) {
        property: 'label'
      }
    ],
    [
      'value',
      MissingPropertyError: A required property is missing
          at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1187:27)
          at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1068:47)
          at ObjectValidator.handle (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1165:17)
          at ObjectValidator.parse (/home/test/test/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
          at /home/test/test/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:654:134
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
          at StringSelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (/home/test/test/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:653:18)
          at StringSelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (/home/test/test/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/StringSelectMenuBuilder.js:48:18)
          at Query.<anonymous> (/home/test/test/src/commands/reward-shop.js:67:9)
          at Query.<anonymous> (/home/test/test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10) {
        property: 'value'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.addOptions()` takes an array, so you'd need to do something along these lines

```js
if (result) {
    const stringselect = [];

    for (const entry in result) {
        const id = result[entry].id;
        const name = result[entry].name;
        const money1 = result[entry].money1;
        const money2 = result[entry].money2;
        const amount = result[entry].amount;

        stringselect.push({
            label: name,
            description: `Of the item ${name} with the id ${id} are ${amount} availible. The price is ${money1} Coin(s), ${money2} Diamond(s).`,
            value: id.toString(),
        });
    }
    
    const select = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('reward-buy')
            .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
            .addOptions(stringselect),
    );
}
```